# Insert error in MeekroDB library

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to use MeekroDB library like this.

```
$data=array('fieldname'=>11221);
DB::insert('tablename',$data);
echo DB::insertId;
```

But I am getting an error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/meekrodb.class.php on line 176 ERROR: If you use named
>   parameters, the second argument must be an array of parameters

I have also tried it this way:

```
$data=array(11221=>'fieldname');
DB::insert('tablename',$data);
echo DB::insertId;
```

Also same error

```
$data=array('fieldname'=>11221);
$param=array('fieldname');
DB::insert('tablename',$data,$param);
echo DB::insertId;
```

also

```
$data=array('fieldname'=>11221);
$param=array('fieldname');
DB::insert('tablename',$param,$data);
echo DB::insertId;
```

Same error

Actually I have tried every possibility but same error occurs again and again.

I could not find any documentation for named parameters. Please fix this and help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

insertId is not a variable, it's a function.

use:

```
echo DB::insertId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$data=array('fieldname'=>11221);
DB::insert('tablename',$data);
$lastID =  DB::insertId();
echo $lastID;
```

instead :

```
$data=array('fieldname'=>11221);
DB::insert('tablename',$data);
echo DB::insertId;
```

Comment: Can you explain why? When adding an answer to an older question with existing answers it is useful to explain what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.